# Create conditional column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, where-clause, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a conditional column in pandas. Here is what the dataframe looks like.

```
    data = [{"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'magie', "dog_is_fluffy" : 1},
            {"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'stellar', "dog_is_fluffy" : 0}, 
            {"owner" : "lisa", "dog" : 'mollie' , "dog_is_fluffy" : 0},
            {"owner" : "lisa", "dog" : 'rex', "dog_is_fluffy" : 0},
            {"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'luns', "dog_is_fluffy" : 1}]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As you can see, my data shows dogs and their owners. We also know if the dog is fluffy. I want to create two columns `fluffy_dogs_owned` and `owner_has_fluffy_dog`.

The result I am looking for is:

```
data_result = [{"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'magie', "dog_is_fluffy" : 1, "fluffy_dogs_owned" : 2, "owner_has_fluffy_dog" : 1},
        {"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'stellar', "dog_is_fluffy" : 0, "fluffy_dogs_owned" : 2, "owner_has_fluffy_dog" : 1}, 
        {"owner" : "lisa", "dog" : 'mollie' , "dog_is_fluffy" : 0, "fluffy_dogs_owned" : 0, "owner_has_fluffy_dog" : 0},
        {"owner" : "lisa", "dog" : 'rex', "dog_is_fluffy" : 0, "fluffy_dogs_owned" : 0, "owner_has_fluffy_dog" : 0},
        {"owner" : "john", "dog" : 'luns', "dog_is_fluffy" : 1, "fluffy_dogs_owned" : 2, "owner_has_fluffy_dog" : 1}]

df_result = pd.DataFrame(data_result)
```

I thought about using `df.groupby()` and `np.where` but I can't make it work so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original Dataframe with `sum` and then compare column for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with casting to integer

```
df['fluffy_dogs_owned'] = df.groupby('owner')['dog_is_fluffy'].transform('sum')
df['owner_has_fluffy_dog'] = df['fluffy_dogs_owned'].ne(0).astype(int)
```

Or with [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['owner_has_fluffy_dog'] = df['fluffy_dogs_owned'].clip(upper=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
       dog  dog_is_fluffy owner  fluffy_dogs_owned  owner_has_fluffy_dog
0    magie              1  john                  2                     1
1  stellar              0  john                  2                     1
2   mollie              0  lisa                  0                     0
3      rex              0  lisa                  0                     0
4     luns              1  john                  2                     1
```